# Karate Robot: Not able to click button using image

Tags: karate

[image]I am using Karate robot for clicking a button using image.
Below is my code:

- robot { app: '^Chrome', highlight: true }
- robot.input('OracleDriver')
- delay(2000)
- robot.click('delete.png')

Sometimes I am able to click delete button for delete.png but other times I am not.
So facing this issue intermittently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, finding by image is indeed not very reliable and should be only used as a backup when normal windows locators don't work.

I have only the following suggestions:

- find a windows locator that works. note that you can navigate from a known locator using `someElement.parent.firstChild` etc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#element-api
- try to standardize the resolution that works best
- see if using OCR works better
- contribute code to Karate to make this better
- look for another solution

Comment: Hi Peter, Our dropdown values are not fixed, it will be a dynamic list as and when user created those entries. Is there any solution/suggestion for locating dynamic dropdown list?

Comment: @BibhutiBhusanSahoo you should be able to get the values from the list and get the value by index. no other suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I tried clicking delete button by using it's class and it is very reliable, below is my code

- waitFor('.icons8-delete-blue').click()

I also followed @Peter's suggestion (someElement.parent.firstChild) and it worked for me!, below is the code

- waitFor('.modal-footer').children[0].click()

Thanks @Peter for the suggestion